# I dont get responses when sending messages using PushSharp

Tags: pushsharp

I send push notifications using PushSharp.

I call the method StopAllServices of PushService object to let it send the messages.

I assume that after PushService.StopAllServices finishes , I got the responses for all the Notification objecs.

Afterwards I kill the thread in which the PushService object is instanciated.

```
PushService = New PushService()
...
...
...

PushService.StopAllServices(True)
...
'the thread dies here
```

I noticed that sometimes I dont get responses in the callback functions.

Can it be that the method StopAllServices doesnt wait for all responses (from APNS/GCM) ?

I need to recieve responses for all Notification objects. How to achive that ?
I'll be glad for sugestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple push Service (APNS) you won't get response for all the successfully delivered notifications and that is "by design". 
**Redth** (the author of pushSharp) posted a detailed explanation of this : http://redth.info/the-problem-with-apples-push-notification-ser/
So you'll barely never get one response-per-notification-sent anyway, not useful to wait for all answers to stop the service.

And keep in mind that delivering the notification to the provider (android/apple/microsoft) doesn't guarantee you the effective device delivery of the notification anyway...

Comment: thanks for you answer. 
My problem is that I dont get these methods fired (sometimes): 
 OnNotificationSendFailure , OnNotificationSent.
So I understand that this behaviour (getting reponses) is achieved by PushSharp logic and not by APNS.
I want to build on PushSharp. Is it a bug in PushSharp or a problrm with the way Im using it ?